# NSG Flow Logs and NSG Diagnostics Difference

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

can someone explaion to me the diffference between the NSG flow and the NSG diagnostics.

Should i enable both or just one for security investigation purposes?

Regards,
Kelly

Searched online couldnt find much information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSG flow logs` as the name suggests allows you to collect and build analytics on top of the ingress/egress IP packets which flows through your NSG (primary objective is to analyze network traffic). Note that flow logs can only be integrated with the storage account i.e.e the BLOB service (or ADLS) and no additional integration is available by default with Event Hub for now.

`Diagnostics log` as the name suggests are a higher-level abstraction of log entity i.e. they provide log details are tenant/resource group (or resources) scope. Note that the diagnostic logs can be streamed to Event Hub and in addition can also be integrated with services such as Azure Monitoring and Storage account (BLOB store or ADLS).